# Define single precision variable in Racket

Tags: racket

I have to run some computations in Racket that I have never used before.

How do I force it to calculate sth in single or half (if it has those) precision floats?

I figured out how to make it compute in big floats:

```
(bf/ (bf 1) (bf 7))
```

I know that the abbreviation for floats (double precision) is *fl*. I cannot figure out the right abbreviation for single floats though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'bigfloat' package you refer to are for *arbitrary* precision floating point numbers. You're very unlikely to want these, as you point out.

It sounds like you're looking for standard IEEE 64-bit floating point numbers. Racket uses these by default, for all inexact arithmetic.

So, for instance:

```
(/ 1 pi)
```

produces

```
0.3183098861837907
```

One possible tripper-upper is that when dividing two rational numbers, the result will again be a rational number. So, for instance,

```
(/ 12347728 298340194)
```

produces

```
6173864/149170097
```

You can force inexact arithmetic either by using `exact->inexact` (always works), or by ensuring that your literals end with decimals (unless you're using the htdp languages).

So, for instance:

```
(/ 12347728.0 298340194.0)
```

produces

```
0.04138808061511148
```

Let me know if this doesn't answer your question....

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there though any way to force racket to compute in 32-bit or 16-bit floating point numbers?

Comment: You can generate 32-bit floats using `real->single-flonum`, or specify them directly as e.g. 3.243f0 or 3f-2. I don't believe there's any support in racket for 16-bit floats. You probably know what you're getting into, but on a modern machine, there's aren't many situations where 32- or 16-bit floats are a good idea. Even in audio applications, 64-bit doubles appear to be taking over. Hope this helps!

Comment: @JohnClements Lower precision floating points are starting to reappear in machine learning applications. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7024.pdf, Ordinary machine learning  typically single precision (32 bit) rather than double because GPU's perform single precision calculations.